# NSString Somehow turn in to an "__NSArrayI" object

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsarray

i am receiving response from my server, it looks like this :

```
2012-09-12 16:29:11.690 WhatIsIt[1763:707] (
    {
    qid = ebb81a9c0c2125c9f12fee33c281dfe2ef5c1596;
    "qid_data" =         {
        labels = Wristwatch;
    };
}  )
```

when i am parsing the `"qid"` value like this :

```
- (void)updateCompleteWithResults:(NSArray*)results{    
       NSLog(@"%@",results);
       NSString *qid = [results valueForKey:@"qid"];
```

the `NSString` object is getting a Parentheses around the string (i dont know how)
looks like this :

```
2012-09-12 16:34:17.979 WhatIsIt[1785:707] (
2e1da5854f3b4f02cd967293cd1364e6d3e0b76a
)
```

so i tried to use :

```
NSString *string = @" spaces in front and at the end ";
NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                              [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

and the app crashes, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the root object of this structure is an array...

If you look at the `valueForKey:` method on [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCIBCDJ) you'll see that it will actually call `valueForKey:` on each of it's members and return the results in another array (this is what you are seeing).

What you should do instead is first get the object you are interested in and then work with it on it's own

```
NSDictionary *myObject = [whatIsIt objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *qId = [myObject objectForKey:@"qid"];
```